# No audio after fresh install of Elementary OS

Tags: audio, elementary-os

No audio after fresh install of Elementary OS, using Asus Zenbook UX433F.

**Kernel**
4.20.6-042006-generic GNU/Linux

**Linux Distro**
DISTRIB_ID=elementary
DISTRIB_RELEASE=5.0
DISTRIB_CODENAME=juno
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="elementary OS 5.0 Juno"
NAME="elementary OS"
VERSION="5.0 Juno"
ID=elementary
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="elementary OS 5.0 Juno"

Answer (score 0):

Changes and updates to fix the problem

**1. A different kernel**

Installing ukuu to upgrade kernel from 4.15 to 4.20.6

In order to use add-apt-repository, install:

> sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
>
> sudo apt-get update

Installing ukuu

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install ukuu

Reboot

**2. Upgrading graphics drivers**

Upgrading nvidia drivers with the nvidia-driver-390 package

> $ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390

Reboot

Comment: There was a bug when audio needs to go through the Nvidia card and the envidia card is not enabled; could be related to that problem.